# How to change style using javascript in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to change style using javascript in reactjs

```
class Hello extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("hello").style.color = 'red';
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="hello" onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am getting error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Comment: This can happen if: 1)No elements were found with that class. 2) If an invalid index is used to access the elements in the array.

Comment: The preferable way would be to not mutate DOM yourself, let React take care of it. React does this more efficiently for you. Use the `style` prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*document.getElementsByClassName* returns you the array of selected elements. Hence,

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

In this case, you need to specify the index of the element to be used.
Notice, [0] below;

document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[0].style.color = 'red';

```js
class Hello extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[0].style.color = 'red';
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="hello" onClick={this.handleClick}> hello </div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

To work on all the elements with the same class, you need to iterate over the array and change the colors for each.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
      let elms = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");

      for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        elms[i].style.color = 'red';
      }
    }
    
    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="hello" onClick={this.handleClick}> hello 1 </div>
            <div className="hello" onClick={this.handleClick}> hello 2 </div>
            <div className="hello" onClick={this.handleClick}> hello 3 </div>
          </div>
           
          
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is working fine but how can i do this for all element of same class

Comment: Added to the answer according to your comment

Comment: Smiles, I dont want to use for lop. I have to find another way. To change style dynamically

Comment: To be honest, that's a different question. I was just helping you to get your original problem solved. If your original question is resolved, feel free to accept the answer, so that somebody stuck with similar question can also be benefitted from this. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sure. I will. But it didnt solve my problem. But You are correct.

Comment: @Biswajit can you explain your use case?

Comment: I wanted to change style of class just like we do in javscript. So that i can use them to make animation.

Comment: your first part of the answer will always pick the first element from dom which have class name 'hello' irrespective of element you click. And second part of answer will cover all the element having class 'hello' on click of any element you click @ivp

Comment: There can be one improvement to the first approach when any component is rendering 'Hello' component that also in a loop and then there you can pass an index inside this component and use that index to manipulate dom

Comment: That is absolutely correct, Shubham. However, the original question does not mention anything of this sort. Ideally, to access the element which is clicked, you don't even have to pass the index, you can directly pass the element which is clicked. But, as I said, nothing of this sort was mentioned or required in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use react way too

```
class Hello extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customColor: {}
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState(() => ({ customColor: { color: 'red' } }));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="hello" style={this.state.customColor} onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The benefit of doing so is that any component created either single or multiple times each of these will have there on set of state and functions and everything. So when I handleclick for one component then it will affect the same component giving it an isolation.